# How to distinct rows by 3 column and get sorted row

Tags: mysql, sql

I have following table,

```
       sc_title      |      sc_date        | sc_coursecode | sc_courseno | sc_courseyear
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Open Water Diver | 2015-01-08 04:00:00 |       ow      |    05W      |    2015
    Open Water Diver | 2015-03-08 04:00:00 |       ow      |    05Z      |    2015
    Open Water Diver | 2015-04-08 04:00:00 |       ow      |    05W      |    2015
    Open Water Diver | 2015-05-18 04:00:00 |       ow      |    05W      |    2015
    Open Water Diver | 2015-05-09 04:00:00 |       ow      |    05Z      |    2015
    Open Water Diver | 2015-05-10 04:00:00 |       ow      |    05W      |    2015
    Open Water Diver | 2015-05-11 04:00:00 |       ow      |    05Z      |    2015
    Open Water Diver | 2015-05-12 04:00:00 |       ow      |    07W      |    2015
    Open Water Diver | 2015-05-13 04:00:00 |       ow      |    05Z      |    2015
    Open Water Diver | 2015-05-14 04:00:00 |       ow      |    07W      |    2015
    Open Water Diver | 2016-05-15 04:00:00 |       ow      |    07C      |    2016
        Bubble Maker | 2015-05-16 04:00:00 |       ow      |    07C      |    2015
```

I need those rows which title(sc_title) are like "Open Water Diver" and distinct by 3 column sc_coursecode, sc_courseno, sc_courseyear and also select only immediate future date row(sc_date). So my will be something like this,

```
       sc_title      |      sc_date        | sc_coursecode | sc_courseno | sc_courseyear
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Open Water Diver | 2015-05-10 04:00:00 |       ow      |    05W      |    2015
    Open Water Diver | 2015-05-09 04:00:00 |       ow      |    05Z      |    2015
    Open Water Diver | 2015-05-12 04:00:00 |       ow      |    07W      |    2015
    Open Water Diver | 2016-05-15 04:00:00 |       ow      |    07C      |    2016
```

I have written following query which is almost works but does not satisfy my final requirement.Getting that distinct row which contains immediate future date(sc_date).

```
SELECT sc_title,sc_date,sc_coursecode,sc_courseno,sc_courseyear 
FROM test_course WHERE DATE(sc_date) > DATE(NOW()) AND sc_title LIKE 'Open Water Diver%' 
GROUP BY sc_coursecode,sc_courseno,sc_courseyear ORDER BY sc_date ASC
```

If any one can help me then that would be great. Thanks in advance

Comment: Think of data in sets... First get a set of data which contains the title and sc_courseno with the min(SC_Date)> today.  then join it back to the base set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are looking for the immediate nearest date, use `MIN` on `sc_date` to pick the earliest one that is greater than `DATE(NOW())`:

```
SELECT
    sc_title
,   MIN(DATE(sc_date))
,   sc_coursecode
,   sc_courseno
,   sc_courseyear 
FROM test_course
WHERE DATE(sc_date) > DATE(NOW())
  AND sc_title LIKE 'Open Water Diver%' 
GROUP BY sc_coursecode, sc_courseno, sc_courseyear
ORDER BY sc_date ASC
```

Note that since you are not grouping by `sc_title` you would get an arbitrary match in the corresponding field when multiple different titles match the `LIKE` condition. To avoid this problem add `sc_title` to the `GROUP BY` list.

Answer (score 0):

Perhapsh something like... (untested)

```
SELECT A.sc_title, A.sc_date, A.sc_coursecode, A.sc_courseno, A.sc_courseyear 
FROM test_course A
INNER JOIN (SELECT min(Sc_date) SC_date, sc_title, sc_CourseCode, sc_courseno, Sc_courseYear
            FROM test_Courase
            where sc_date>=now()
            GROUP BY sc_title, sc_CourseCode, sc_courseno, Sc_courseYear) B
 on B.SC_date = A.Sc_date
and B.sc_title = A.Sc_Title
and B.Sc_CourseCode = A.SC_courseCode
and B.Sc_CourseYear = A.SC_CourseYear
WHERE A.sc_title LIKE 'Open Water Diver%'
```